# Re-entry to Germany within 1 month after leaving a job with a valid EU blue card?

Tags: uk, indian-citizens, germany, multiple-entry, blue-card

I left Germany to start a new job in the UK. My blue card is valid until 2025. Can I travel back to Germany within 2 months with the same card?

Comment: This question likely is better suited for SE Expatriates.

Comment: @travelgasm if the question is about short term travel to Germany then it's on topic here.

Comment: @MJeffryes No problem!

Comment: Did you notify the competent immigration authority of your new circumstances? It seems to me that you no longer fulfil the conditions of the blue card, and may therefore no longer be entitled to use it

Answer (score 3):

According to §51 AufenthG your Blue Card expires in the following cases:

*6.  if the foreigner leaves the federal territory for a reason which is not temporary in nature,*

*7.  if the foreigner leaves the federal territory and does not re-enter the federal territory within six months or within a longer period set by the foreigners authority,*

Even though six months have not yet passed since you left the country, leaving for work in another country will most likely be considered a non-temporary departure.

If you have not notified Ausländerbehörde, it is likely that they do not know the reason for your departure. However, even if you are allowed to go through the border, your residence permit has legally expired at the moment when you left to the UK.